# AWS Lambda using Asynchronous code returns NULL

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda, async-await

This question is a follow up question, the link to the other question is -- 
[aws lambda function async connection query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52258368/aws-lambda-function-async-connection-query/60221366#60221366)

I am developing server code using AWS Lambda and to test the asynchronous connection I am using the same code provided by Trung with improvement by giankotarola and the output of the Lambda Function comes only if I replace  --

`1. return callback(null, {body: JSON.stringify(result),statusCode:200});`

with --

`2. return result;`

Also, at the following line --

`3. pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {`

It gives a warning:  `Expected Error to be handled`

I cannot understand why the code at Line 1. mentioned above doesn't work ? And how to handle the warning at 3.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post some code directly here as part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is because the function is using `async`. With `async` functions you just return the result. The `callback` is used when you are not using `async`.

I believe the second issue is because the `err` on that call isn't handled. There is a handler for the second `err`, but not this one. Basically that code should look like this:

```js
let getOrder = async (sql, params) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
            if (err){
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                connection.query(sql, params, (err, results) => {
                    if (err){
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("-----Query Done!");
                        connection.release();
                        console.log("-----Data: ", results);
                        resolve(results);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you Jason. I did not see the error handling for the second part. After handling the err, the warning disappears.